# Linux - Get X days before today's date where X is a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I have a scenario where I need to calculate the date (yyyy-mm-dd) for X days from today's date in Linux. X is a user-input.

I tried the following:

```
X="-30"
date -d '$X day' '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

But this produces the following error:

```
date: invalid date ‘$X day’
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

try this `X="-30"
date -d "$X day" '+%Y-%m-%d'`

the $X variable won't expand in single quotes, which is the problem

Comment: didn't this work for you?